# How to make KDE Spectacle automatically save a picture?

Tags: screenshot, kde-plasma, spectacle

The "PrtScr" key in KDE in Ubuntu 18.04 invokes "spectacle", which pops up as a separate window.  You can click "save and exit" to save a screenshot.  The hotkeys that launch Spectacle appear to be defined in /usr/share/khotkeys/spectacle.khotkeys .

Is there a way of changing the settings so that it "just saves the screenshot" (i.e. there's no clumsy sequence of "press PrtScn, go to where spectacle has launched, press Save and Exit" each time)?

Comment: ditto - this seems like the single most obvious setting you'd want in a screenshot application.  auto-save, yaaa???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use shortcut keys.

**Meta+Print** will take a screenshot of the active window.

**Shift+Print** will take a screenshot of your entire desktop, i.e. all monitors.

**Meta+Shift+Print** will take a rectangular region screenshot.

https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/spectacle/spectacle/starting.html

Comment: Thanks - "Meta+PrtSc" etc. don't have the "save and exit" dialog that "PrtSc" on its own does, and taking a screenshot of the active window is what I'm looking for most often.

Answer (score 1):

- Enter Settings > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts
- Create new custom group ie "Spectacle": Edit > New Group
- And create new custom shortcut(s): Edit > New > Global Shortcut > Command/URL
- fill the name, e.g. "Region Capture"
- Trigger: Print
- And in Action Tab put the following in Command/URL

`spectacle -brc -o "$HOME/pictures/screenshots/Screenshot_$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S').png"`
[image]

- Save the config
- Press PrintScreen button or the one that you configured before
- Click twice and voilà :)